# How to vertically align these elements inside a span?

Tags: html, css, user-interface, prototype, user-experience

Here is the prototype I am trying to implement.[image]

Here is what I have right now

[image]

What I am trying to do right now is vertically align all the elements(`span`s with image and text) - My Account, Cards, Travel, etc..

Here is my HTML and CSS for this section

**HTML:**

```
   <div id="header">
      <img class ="header_component" src="Logo.PNG" />
      <span class="header_component">
        <img src="MyAccount.PNG"/><BR/>
        My Account
      </span>
      <span class="header_component">
        <img src="Cards.PNG"/> <BR />
        Cards
      </span>
      <span class="header_component">
        <img src="Cards.PNG"/> <BR />
        Travel
      </span>
      <span class="header_component">
        <img src="Rewards.PNG"/> <BR />
        Rewards
      </span>
      <span class="header_component">
        <img src="Business.PNG"/> <BR />
        Business
      </span>
    </div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.header_component {
    width: 12%;
    float:left;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle; 
}
```

I tried applying the `vertical-align: middle` attribute I learned from  Vertical Alignment but that didn't do the job(elements not vertically aligned in `span`).

Does anyone know of any alternative styles that could work?

Comment: try setting `height:100%;` on the css of .header_component

Comment: a jsfiddle would be great to help with the issue!

Comment: @DavidAnderton Thanks but didn't work.  I go make a jsfiddle for this right now.

Comment: Looks like a phishing site to me

Comment: Next question on SO - "How do I inject XSS into American Express to redirect to my site?"

Comment: no phishing haha - https://www.topcoder.com/challenge-details/30049985/?type=develop&lc=

Comment: haha! Share the money if you win?

Comment: @SnehalShah haha of course I will but as a beginner I am not close to winning these yet. Just for practice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've restructured slightly to add a wrapper around the contents of each item (for centering) and change `float` to `inline-block` to the header item. `white-space: nowrap` on the parent fixes line breaking issues.

```css
#header {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
.header_component {
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
.header_component div {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  margin-top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img class="header_component" src="Logo.PNG" />
  <span class="header_component">
    <div class="inner">
      <img src="MyAccount.PNG"/><br />
      My Account
    </div>
  </span>
  <span class="header_component">
    <div class="inner">
      <img src="Cards.PNG"/><br />
      Cards
    </div>
  </span>
  <span class="header_component">
    <div class="inner">
      <img src="Cards.PNG"/><br />
      Travel
    </div>
  </span>
  <span class="header_component">
    <div class="inner">
      <img src="Rewards.PNG"/><br />
      Rewards
    </div>
  </span>
  <span class="header_component">
    <div class="inner">
      <img src="Business.PNG"/><br />
      Business
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

Comment: quick question: Why have css #header {white-space: nowrap;} in the CSS? I saw what that did on http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp. I got rid of it and it still looked fine. Is that more of a style attribute in case I wanted to write more on that line?